# will installing visual studio 2010 install .net framework 2.0+

Tags: visual-studio-2010

which versions of the .net framework are installed when you install visual studio 2010.  if i need to work on projects with multiple target frameworks (on a fresh machine) do i need to install .net framework version up front before installing vs 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It installs .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

It installs .NET 4.0 as a default, but you can download the .NET 2.0 package [link text](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Installing Visual Studio 2010 will only install the .Net 4.0 framework by default.  The other frameworks and SDK's can be separately installed before or after Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Installing VS 2010 should install all versions of .NET, and your target framework should be selectable on project creation.  If they aren't, you should be able to download them from Microsoft.

Comment: Can you even have a Windows box post XP SP3 without it? I know that Vista can't even run w/out it.

Comment: I wouldn't think you could, seeing as how Microsoft likes to use C# if not at least managed C++ (more managed C++.... ugh...) for their applications and services.  For example, Windows PowerShell.  I wouldn't be surprised if Windows 8 required silverlight...

Comment: what do you mean it installs all of them?  even 1.1, 2.0 ??

Comment: From what I have seen, the .NET framework builds upon itself.  So, the old versions are normally installed along with the new ones.  If you take a look at your C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework, you will see all the versions listed